# How can i combine words from input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example if i have form like this:

```
  <form >
        <input type="text" name="name" id="my_input">
        <input id="search_tags" type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
```

And i wrote words 'example' and 'item' value of `#my_input'` will be 'example item'. How can i build from written words something like this: `'/example-item/'`?

Comment: If you're sending it to a server to work on, and not just using it locally, I would combine it on the server, with optionally in the client browser, if you can.

Comment: I need to combine it before sneding because i will use that combined words as a get url.

Comment: Note, I'm not telling you not to, just warning that doing it only in the browser is less reliable than also doing it on the server. If it's PHP, you could do it with a `header()` redirect as well and the user would never know.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand everything in english. I am not using php, and i still don't know what about You are talking, but it is my guilt. Thank You for all.

Comment: I'm just saying do the GET string replace on the server *if you can*. Try entering text and submitting on this form and note the user never sees the redirect: http://jfcoder.com/test/getredirect.php You don't require PHP to do this, but that's the only language I know how to do it.

Comment: Maybe i will do that if it will be needed and if i will understand a little more of programming.

Comment: This is the PHP code that makes it work: http://jfcoder.com/test/getredirect.php?show=true Note, this is meant as a demonstration, actual production-value code would need to be tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var combinedWord = "/" + $("#my_input").val().replace(/ /g, "-") + "/";
```

Comment: Thank You. After 11 minutes i will accept this answer as a right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all spaces with a hyphen:

```
var my_input_val = $('#my_input').val().replace(/\s/g, '-');
```

And then concatenate the forward slashes onto either end:

```
var concat_my_input = '/' + my_input_val + '/';
```

`.replace()` is a very flexible function that can either match with a regular expression or a string. See the [w3chools definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) for more information.

Comment: If you don't use regular expressions with the global modifier, `replace` will only substitute the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex.. maybe something like value.replace(/[^\w\d]+/gi, '-'); It'll replace anything that isn't a number or letter.. which looks like what you might want to be doing.

```
var value = "example item 2";
value.replace(/[^\w\d]+/gi, '-');

console.log(value) // will be example-item-2

value = '/' + value + '/';
console.log(value) // will be '/example-item-2/'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it for each of your input then

```
var combinedWord;

$("input[type=text]").each(function()
{
combinedWord+=$(this).val();    //if space between different input is to be maintained then add .replace(' ', '-') here
});

return "/" + combinedWord + "/"; //if all spaces need to be replaced add .replace(' ', '-') here.
```